# Arbitrarity of $i$ in the propagator

Tags: definition, conventions, complex-numbers, greens-functions, propagator

My question is simple: **how arbitrary can the factor in front of the propagator be?**

What I mean by that is, if we call the wave operator $K$ and the propagator $G$, I've seen different books use different notations:
$$KG=\delta$$
$$KG=-\delta$$
$$KG=i\delta$$
$$KG=-i\delta$$
Are all of these equivalent? Are there other conventions besides the ones I wrote? How should I guess which one was used?
In case this is of help to answer my question, my doubt came when, to write the inverse of the scalar propagator $\frac{i}{p^2-m^2}$, I saw $(p^2-m^2)$, with no $i$ factor.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by these being "equivalent"? I mean, obviously the $G$ defined by these four equations are four different mathematical objects, right?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Of course, since $K$ is the same object. I mean that if I want to (consistently)  use the first one instead of the third one, I can still regularize, renormalize, evaluate loop diagrams, and ultimately all my observables will be the same.

Comment: I mean...you're going to get factors of $\mathrm{i}$ in other places too if you choose a different convention, I don't know what you mean by whether you "can still regularize". You're just substituting $G$ by $-G$ or $\mathrm{i}G$, it's just tracking signs.

Comment: @ACuriousMind that's pleasant to know: I didn't know it, that's all. You'll agree that not all factors are a matter of convention: I didn't know whether this was the case. It seemed plausible, but not obvious, at least to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying - in my eyes, whether or not a definition including factors of $\mathrm{i}$ is a "matter of convention" or not is merely a historical artifact of whether or not we've been unfortunate enough to have different influential people make different choices. There's no good objective *reason* why you'd be free to choose your definition of $G$ but not that of a different quantity - ultimately *all* definitions are "matters of convention", it's just that in the majority of cases there is only one common convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how arbitrary can the factor in front of the propagator be?

You are free to choose whatever definition you like, whether it is:
$$KG=\delta$$
or
$$KG=-\delta$$
or
$$KG=i\delta$$
or
$$KG=-i\delta\;,.$$
But, clearly, if the $K$ is the same in these equations above, the $G$ is different. The difference is fairly trivial, but a difference nonetheless.

I wouldn't typically describe this as "arbitrary," but as a matter of convention. Although, if you want to say arbitrary, no one can stop you. It just seems a little flippant to me, since it seems to disregard that there *could* be a reason for the convention.

From dictionary.com:

> "Arbitrary - *Adjective* - subject to individual will or judgment without restriction; contingent solely upon one's discretion..."

From Google.com:

> "Arbitrary... based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system."

Once you have made a choice of convention, you should stick with it to avoid confusion. Different books make different choices because their authors chose different conventions.

To directly answer your question: The factor in front can be as "arbitrary" as you would like. Choose whatever convention you want, but if you choose an unfamiliar convention you are going to have to explain yourself to everyone else in the world who doesn't use that convention. The explanation will be short, but pretty much pointless. (In addition, as pointed out in the comments, if insert a factor of 42 for no reason, you are going to have to carry that factor around and explicitly write it out.)

And to answer your additional questions:

> Are all of these equivalent?

No.

> Are there other conventions besides the ones I wrote?

Maybe, but those seem like they would contain the major ones.

> How should I guess which one was used?

You should not guess if you don't have to. Look at the equation the author is solving and you should see what the convention is.

> In case this is of help to answer my question, my doubt came when, to write the inverse of the scalar propagator $\frac{i}{p^2-m^2}$, I saw $(p^2-m^2)$, with no $i$ factor.

The inverse of $\frac{i}{p^2-m^2}$ is not $(p^2-m^2)$. The inverse of $\frac{i}{p^2-m^2}$ is $-i(p^2-m^2)$.

In general, we can say that the inverse of $X$, $X^{-1}$, satisfies $XX^{-1}=1$. If X is not a c-number then we could define right and left inverses.

Comment: You're right: arbitrarity isn't the right word. Is there a limit to the conventionality of this factor? Could I define, in my QFT book, the propagator as $KG=42\delta$?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti _Arbitrariness_ is, though.

Comment: @MauroGiliberti You can define it however you want. But why would you want to stick in a factor of 42? If there is no reason, then "arbitrary" is a better word.

Comment: arbitrary: "based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system."

Comment: Often you will see authors choosing to insert factors of $2\pi$ or of $i$ or of $\sqrt{2\omega}$ or whatever, but there is often a reason. With respect to $i$ or $-i$ or $-1$, the reason is possibly that the momentum space result looks cleaner.

Comment: Like, if you want a factor of ${42}$ sitting in front of your propagator then sure go ahead and stick in a factor of 42.

Comment: But if you do stick a factor of $42$ in front of your propagator, just remember that to convert formulas you read in QFT books into your choice of conventions, you will need to correct the book's results by factors like $42$ or $1/42$ or $1/\sqrt{42}$.

Comment: In general, what you will tend to find is that your calculations will involve a lot of factors of $42$ in intermediate steps, and that suddenly at the very end of the calculation all these various factors will "magically" cancel out. The fact that the intermediate steps of the calculation are more complicated (since they have these factors), but the final answer for an observable quantity will be simpler (since the factors will cancel), is a clue that you can simplify your formalism. In fact you've essentially just made your life more difficult by putting the $42$ in by hand.

Comment: Your answer, together with the chat discussion, ultimately cleared the fog. About the last paragraph, I've fallen victim of the same "convention confusion": if the propagator is defined with $i$, then the 2-vertex is *also* defined as **$i$ times** the inverse of the propagator.